# How to find next li tag dynamically

Tags: jquery, search, jquery-mobile, dynamic

I am trying to find next `li` tag on `checkbox` click. I tried some approaches(closet,parent) but getting undefined error. 
I have created function and am passing checkbox id to it.
Here is my code

#### HTML

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain" id="liDoorConcerns" style="display: none;">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-role="fieldcontain">
        <legend></legend>

        <input type="checkbox" name="DoorMissing" id="DoorMissing" />
        <label style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px" for="DoorMissing">Missing</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="DoorDamaged" id="DoorDamaged" />
        <label style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px" for="DoorDamaged">Damaged</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="DoorBoardedUp" id="DoorBoardedUp" />
        <label style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px" for="DoorBoardedUp">Boarded up</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="DoorPaint" id="DoorPaint" />
        <label style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px" for="DoorPaint">Paint</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="DoorDryRot" id="DoorDryRot" />
        <label style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px" for="DoorDryRot">Dry Rot</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="DoorOther" id="DoorOther" />
        <label style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px" for="DoorOther">Other</label>
    </fieldset>
</li>

<li data-role="fieldcontain" id="liDoorConcernsComments" style="display:none;">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-role="fieldcontain">
        <legend></legend>
        <textarea cols="20" id="DoorConcernsComments"    name="DoorConcernsComments" rows="2"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
</li>
```

#### JS Code:

```
function test(ida) {
    debugger;
    var element = $('#' + ida);
    var get = element.find('li');
    var li_id = get.first().id;
    alert("id" + li_id);
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: From where you are calling this `test()` and can you please create JS Fiddle?

Comment: am calling test from checkbox click event

Comment: why are you `find`ing an `li` inside an `li`?

Comment: I need to show/ hide on checkbox click, I have this functionality on every page so wanted to make it dynamic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you're going about this the wrong way. Try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    var li = $(this).closest('li').next('li');

    alert(li.prop('id'));
});
```

All you need to do is get the closest `<li>`, then find the `<li>` after that. Constructing selectors from strings isn't necessary.

Your undefined error is likely stemming from this line:

```
alert("id" + li_id);
```

The element `li_id` is a jQuery object, which doesn't have an `.id` property. To get this, either use `li.prop('id')` or `li[0].id`.

Comment: Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/j37wg/). It's easier using `$(this).closest('li').next('li')[0].id;`

Comment: Thanks Omar it worked for me for click as well as for edit mode

Comment: @Bojangles where is id stored in `data-`? `attr` seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/j37wg/1/ btw +1 for a solution that works in mobile

Comment: @user2153497 Oh yes - I didn't see it was just `id` and not `data-id`. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

Check sample on jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rhP3E/

I have created function which will find id of next li on checkbox click

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        alert($(this).parent().parent().next('li').attr('id'));
    });
```

Comment: Check this link. it is working with jQuery mobile as well
http://jsfiddle.net/rhP3E/2/

Comment: Yea i know, it's different than your posted answer and first js demo :) using `.parent()` doesn't always work with JQM since it enhances markup dynamically and adds extra divs. Using `.closest()` is safer.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you are looking for a code that tells you the next `<li>` after you have clicked a checkbox.

Please see below for code:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
 var parentLI = $(this).closest('li').next().attr('id');
 console.clear();
 console.log(parentLI);
});
```

Please see [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sZwUA/) for jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Mobile enhances markup dynamically by adding `div`'s, `span`'s and `class`es. This been said, using `.parent()` to find an element in `DOM` *doesn't always* achieve desirable results. Therefore, using `.closest()` instead is guaranteed and safer.

Here is an approach I always use to find elements and fetch their `id`.

```
$('[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
 var first =  $(this).closest('li').next('li')[0].id;
 alert(first);
});
```

`$(this).closest('li').next('li')` will result an `[object]`, to fetch the `id` without extra code, use `[0].id` where `[0]` is the index of the first object in the array.

This approach is useful when using `.nextAll()` and `.prevAll()` when your array results many objects.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/j37wg/)**